# Looking for class of Wordpress audio player volume level

Tags: css, wordpress, audio, css-selectors

I've redesigned every element of the default Wordpress audio player but I cannot determine the correct class id for the volume level. This is what I have but it's not working:

```
.mejs-controls .mejs-horizontal-volume-total .mejs-horizontal-volume-slider {
   color: #cc3333 !important;
}
```

Here's a sample page: [audio player at bottom of page](https://partyfavorz.com/change-the-situation-immerse-yourself-in-the-latest-sounds-from-the-underground/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the correct selector, and `background` instead of `color`:

```
.mejs-controls .mejs-horizontal-volume-slider .mejs-horizontal-volume-current{
  background: #cc3333;
}
```